# Chess - Avoiding Infinite Recursion when Preventing Check

Tags: algorithm, recursion, artificial-intelligence, game-engine, chess

I have an algorithm as follows to prevent a player from choosing a move that puts it into check:

1. Fake the move (by copying the board and working on the copied board)
2. ***Get all legal opponent moves*** after the move has been faked.
3. If one of the legal moves can attack the player's king, then the originally faked move cannot be chosen.

However, in step 2 (bolded), the program must check that whatever the other player does does not move the other player into check. This creates an infinite recursion that I'm not sure algorithmically how to avoid. What suggestions do people have for this situation?

Comment: "the program must check that whatever the other player does does not move the other player into check" No the program should not check this condition in this situation. [Case in point](https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/8/8/7k/6r1/R3KQ2_w_KQkq_-) 1.Ke2 is not legal even though black cannot move their rook.

Comment: Why would it not be legal? Wouldn't it not be in check since black can't do anything to take the king?

Comment: No, the official chess rules published by FIDE explicitly address this situation in paragraph 3.9. You should read the rules before trying to implement a chess engine.

Comment: [wikipedia rules of chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_chess#Check) obviously isn't a primary source, but still: "A piece unable to move because it would place its own king in check (it is pinned against its own king) **may still deliver check to the opposing player**."

Comment: You can add maxDepth parameter to your recursive functions, give it 0 where you want it to run all the way down to the base conditions, or N to force it to stop after N recursive calls, & unless it run parallel, you can pass the board copy from father-to-child along with the enumerated move to apply within the recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

You can define another function which returns `true` if the player's piece can move to the cell of the opponent's king and `false` otherwise.

Now call this function for the opponent when you fake a move.

Comment: But don't we need to check that the opponent wouldn't put itself into check? To determine if in fact the first player's piece truly is in check? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the definition of check/what counts and doesn't count...

Comment: But to get the legal moves, we have to prevent checks...this is where my recursion loop is happening

Comment: After a fake move, you don't need to verify that the opponent's king is in threat or not. If the opponent can directly attack the king, it doesn't matter if its king is in danger or not, since it will knock out the king and the game is over.

Hence a legal move in this function just means that wether it can move to the king's cell or not.